# How to get groupby sum of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
index col1   col2   col3   col4   col5
0     a      c      1      2      f 
1     a      c      1      2      f
2     a      d      1      2      f
3     b      d      1      2      g
4     b      e      1      2      g
5     b      e      1      2      g
```

**I want to group by col1 and col2 and get the `sum()` of col3 and col4.** `col5` can be dropped since the data can not be aggregated.

Here is what the output should look like. I am interested in having both `col3` and `col4` in the resulting dataframe. It doesn't really matter if `col1` and `col2` are part of the index or not.

```
index col1   col2   col3   col4   
0     a      c      2      4          
1     a      d      1      2      
2     b      d      1      2      
3     b      e      2      4
```

Here is what I tried:

```
df_new = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3', 'col4'].sum()
```

That however only returns the aggregated results of `col4`.

How do I make it work?

Comment: The issue is likely that `df.col3.dtype` is likely not an `int` or a numeric datatype. Try `df.col3 = df.col3.astype(int)` before doing your `groupby`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

By using `apply`

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])["col3", "col4"].apply(lambda x : x.astype(int).sum())
Out[1257]: 
           col3  col4
col1 col2            
a    c        2     4
     d        1     2
b    d        1     2
     e        2     4
```

If you want to `agg`

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).agg({'col3':'sum','col4':'sum'})
```

Comment: Why is this rated so much higher than ```df.groupby([col1','col2'])[['col3','col4']].sum()```

Comment: @JustinBeresford Here is what I tried:

df_new = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3', 'col4'].sum()
That however only returns the aggregated results of col4.

Comment: The `apply(lambda)` soluction results in this warning for me: `Indexing with multiple keys (implicitly converted to a tuple of keys) will be deprecated, use a list instead.`

Comment: @MikeB 
`["col3", "col4"]` should be `[["col3", "col4"]]` in order to select columns by passing a list. Without the inner square brackets,  `"col3", "col4"` is interpreted as a tuple. @BENY would be great if you could edit the answer as it asks me for at least 6 character changes when trying to do so.

Answer (score 64):

Another generic solution is

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2']).agg({'col3':'sum','col4':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

This will give you the required output.

**UPDATED (June 2020):**
Introduced in Pandas 0.25.0, Pandas has added new groupby behavior *“named aggregation”* and *tuples*, for naming the output columns when applying multiple aggregation functions to specific columns.

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2']).agg(
     sum_col3 = ('col3','sum'),
     sum_col4 = ('col4','sum'),
     ).reset_index()
```

Also, you can **name new columns**, e.g. I've used 'sum_col3' and 'sum_col4', but you can use any name you want.

Refer to [Link](https://keytodatascience.com/groupby-pandas-python) for detailed description.

Answer (score 13):

Due to pandas FutureWarning: Indexing with multiple keys discussed on [GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23566) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60999753/pandas-future-warning-indexing-with-multiple-keys), I recommend this solution:

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])[['col3', 'col4']].sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

[image: output dataframe]

Answer (score 6):

The above answer didn't work for me.

```
df_new = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).sum()[["col3", "col4"]]
```

I was grouping by single group by and sum columns.

Here is the one worked for me.

```
D1.groupby(['col1'])['col2'].sum() << The sum at the end not the middle.
```

Comment: Have you tried :df_new = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])[["col3", "col4"]].sum() ?
This one worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is likely that `df.col3.dtype` is likely not an `int` or a numeric datatype. Try `df.col3 = df.col3.astype(int)` before doing your `groupby`

Additionally, select your columns after the groupby to see if the columns are even being aggregated:

```
df_new = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).sum()[["col3", "col4"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You miss a pair of square brackets to select necessary columns in your `DataFrameGroupBy` object:

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])[['col3', 'col4']].sum()
```

You can also drop columns you don't need before `groupby`:

```
df.drop('col5', axis=1).groupby(['col1', 'col2']).sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be more efficient to do the following:

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).agg({'col3':'sum','col4':'sum'}).sum(axis=1)
```

or:

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3', 'col4'].sum().sum(axis=1)
```

This does assume you have appropriate types in the dataframe.