# Get mean per column per partition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, mean, partition

I am trying to get a mean value per column per partition for a DataFrame such as this one:

```
  country      city  sales  stock
0      UK    London      1     34
1      UK     Leeds      2     20
2      UK     Leeds      3     21
3      RO      Cluj      4     24
4      RO      Cluj      5     25
5      RO Bucharest      6     25
```

That is, I want to get an average of both `sales` and `stock`, and aggregating these into unique combinations of `country` and `city`. The resulting DataFrame should therefore be:

```
  country      city  sales  stock
0      UK    London      1     34
1      UK     Leeds    2.5   20.5
2      RO      Cluj    4.5   24.5
3      RO Bucharest      6     25
```

where duplicate rows of my country-city partition have been aggregated into a single row, with mean values.

I studied the documentation on `pandas.DataFrame.mean()` and SO questions & answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037298/pandas-get-column-average-mean), but none help me in a straightforward manner. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431243/pandas-dataframe-groupby-how-to-get-sum-of-multiple-columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`groupby`

```
df.groupby(['country', 'city']).mean()

                   sales  stock
country city                   
RO      Bucharest    6.0   25.0
        Cluj         4.5   24.5
UK      Leeds        2.5   20.5
        London       1.0   34.0
```

---

Setting the index

```
df.set_index(['country', 'city']).mean(level=[0, 1])
```

---

Without setting the index

```
df.groupby(['country', 'city'], as_index=False, sort=False).mean()


  country       city  sales  stock
0      UK     London    1.0   34.0
1      UK      Leeds    2.5   20.5
2      RO       Cluj    4.5   24.5
3      RO  Bucharest    6.0   25.0
```

Comment: To be precise, `df.groupby(['country', 'city'], as_index=False, sort=False).mean()`