# Python FutureWarning: Indexing with multiple keys (implicitly converted to a tuple of keys)

Tags: python, group-by

I've recently upgraded Python to 3.7.6 and my existing code:

```
df['Simple_Avg_Return'] = df.groupby(['YF_Ticker'])['Share_Price_Delta_Percent', 'Dividend_Percent'].transform(
        sum).divide(2).round(2)
```

Is now throwing this warning:

```
FutureWarning: Indexing with multiple keys (implicitly converted to a
tuple of keys) will be deprecated, use a list instead.
```

How would I go about converting this to a list as advised and where?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas, Future Warning: Indexing with multiple keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60999753/pandas-future-warning-indexing-with-multiple-keys)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use an extra bracket around `['Share_Price_Delta_Percent', 'Dividend_Percent']`

Like this,

```
df['Simple_Avg_Return'] = df.groupby(['YF_Ticker'])[['Share_Price_Delta_Percent', 'Dividend_Percent']].transform(
        sum).divide(2).round(2)
```

Quoting @ALollz comment

> The decision was made https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23566. To
>   keep compatibility between 0.25 and 1.0 they didn't remove the feature
>   but added a warning in 1.0. Likely it will be removed in the next
>   major deprecation cycle.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61000091/11701676)