# Grouping data month-wise with Categorical data in pandas

Tags: pandas, group, categorical

How can I group data into months from dates where a data frame has both categorical and numerical data in pandas. I tried the groupby function but I think it won't work with categorical data. There are multiple values in the categorical column. Sample data:

| Date | Campaign_Name | No_of_Male_Viewers | No_of_Female_Viewers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-12 | Dove_birds | 1268 | 7656 |
| 2021-02-05 | Pantene_winner | 657 | 8964 |
| 2021-09-15 | Budweiser_wazap | 7642 | 76 |
| 2021-05-13 | Pantene_winner | 425 | 6578 |
| 2021-12-12 | Budweiser_wazap | 9867 | 111 |
| 2021-09-09 | Dove_birds | 1578 | 11456 |
| 2021-05-24 | Pantene_winner | 678 | 7475 |
| 2021-09-27 | Budweiser_wazap | 8742 | 96 |
| 2021-09-09 | Dove_soft | 1175 | 15486 |

Now I need to group the data months wise and show for example that Budweiser_wazap in September gained a total audience of xxxx and in December gained xxxx audience and so on for the other campaigns as well.

Expected output sample:

| Month | Campaign_Name | No_of_Male_Viewers | No_of_Female_Viewers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| February | Pantene_winner | 657 | 8964 |
| September | Budweiser_wazap | 16384 | 172 |

Since **Budweiser_wazap** **campaign ran twice in September**, the **resulting output** for **No_of_Male_Viewers** is: **7642 + 8742 = 16384**, and for **No_of_Female_Viewers** is: **76 + 96 = 172**.

Comment: groupby itself just segments the data - there is no restriction on what the column types are.  What is the expected output?

Comment: Added it in my question. In September Budweiser aired twice but it aggregates the viewership.

Comment: please provide actual values.  That is the only way to distinguish which of the many similar operations you are actually interested in

Comment: I've updated my question, I think this might clarify what I need to accomplish

Comment: note that you will want to alos group by `year` if rows with 05/2020 and 05/2021 should be treated/summed separately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE-

```
##Get Month Name for each date
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.month_name()

#Groupby `Month` & `Campaign_Name`
df.groupby(['Month', 'Campaign_Name'])[['No_of_Male_viewers', 'No_of_Female_viewers']].sum().reset_index()
df
```

Sample Reproducible code-

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date' : ['2015-06-08', '2015-08-05', '2015-05-06', '2015-05-05', '2015-07-08', '2015-05-07', '2015-06-05', '2015-07-05'], 
    'Sym'  : ['aapl', 'aapl', 'aapl', 'aapl', 'aaww', 'aaww', 'aaww', 'aaww'], 
    'Data2': [11, 8, 10, 15, 110, 60, 100, 40],
    'Data3': [5, 8, 6, 1, 50, 100, 60, 120]
})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.month_name()
df
```

df output-

```
Date           Sym  Data2   Data3  Month
0   2015-06-08  aapl    11  5   June
1   2015-08-05  aapl    8   8   August
2   2015-05-06  aapl    10  6   May
3   2015-05-05  aapl    15  1   May
4   2015-07-08  aaww    110 50  July
5   2015-05-07  aaww    60  100 May
6   2015-06-05  aaww    100 60  June
7   2015-07-05  aaww    40  120 July
```

Groupby Condition-

```
df.groupby(['Month', 'Sym'])[['Data2', 'Data3']].sum().reset_index()
```

Output-

```
    Month   Sym   Data2 Data3
0   August  aapl    8   8
1   July    aaww    150 170
2   June    aapl    11  5
3   June    aaww    100 60
4   May     aapl    25  7
5   May     aaww    60  100
```

Ref link- [Pandas - dataframe groupby - how to get sum of multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431243/pandas-dataframe-groupby-how-to-get-sum-of-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0):

If you use strftime('%B') - that automatically extracts Month names - you can reach the same result with one line of code :)

```
#download dataframe from Stackoverflw and convert column to datetime
df=pd.read_clipboard()
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)

#'%B' - will return full month name, '%b' - 3-Letter- like Dec, Sep
df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B'), "Campaign_Name"]).sum()
```

Here is how the output looks like:
[image]