# Grouby and Sum Across Multiple Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

How can I groupby and sum across multiple columns in a DataFrame, while preserving the DataFrame's original "look"? Here is what I mean:

Code/Data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"State": ["NM", "NM", "NM", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX"],
                   "County": ["Lea", "Lea", "Chaves", "Lamb", "Lamb", "Lubbock", "Lubbock", "Denton"],
                   "Name": ["Mike", "Mike", "Cash", "Mary", "Mary", "Addison", "Addison", "Jen"],
                   "Checking": [50, 100, 25, 1000, 360, 9, 100, 200],
                  "Savings": [100, 200, 75, 300, 300, 10000, 250, 75]})

print(df)
```

```
    State   County     Name  Checking  Savings
0      NM      Lea     Mike        50      100
1      NM      Lea     Mike       100      200
2      NM   Chaves     Cash        25       75
3      TX     Lamb     Mary      1000      300
4      TX     Lamb     Mary       360      300
5      TX  Lubbock  Addison         9    10000
6      TX  Lubbock  Addison       100      250
7      TX   Denton      Jen       200       75
```

Here is my desired output. I've left out the index, as I'm indifferent as to how it appears in the end, as long as I get the result below. Note how for every State, County, and Name combination I sum separately both the Checking and Savings columns. For example, there is only one row for NM -> Lea -> Mike, where the Checking and Savings columns have the sum for all rows matching said conditions.

```
   State   County     Name  Checking  Savings
      NM      Lea     Mike       150      300
      NM   Chaves     Cash        25       75
      TX     Lamb     Mary      1360      600
      TX  Lubbock  Addison       109    10250
      TX   Denton      Jen       200       75
```

The first challenge is grouping by the first three columns and then summing up the last two columns separately. The second challenge is getting the array to match this format, with no nested/multilayer indices or columns.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"State": ["NM", "NM", "NM", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX"],
                   "County": ["Lea", "Lea", "Chaves", "Lamb", "Lamb", "Lubbock", "Lubbock", "Denton"],
                   "Name": ["Mike", "Mike", "Cash", "Mary", "Mary", "Addison", "Addison", "Jen"],
                   "Checking": [50, 100, 25, 1000, 360, 9, 100, 200],
                  "Savings": [100, 200, 75, 300, 300, 10000, 250, 75]})
```

---

```
print(df)

    State   County     Name  Checking  Savings
0      NM      Lea     Mike        50      100
1      NM      Lea     Mike       100      200
2      NM   Chaves     Cash        25       75
3      TX     Lamb     Mary      1000      300
4      TX     Lamb     Mary       360      300
5      TX  Lubbock  Addison         9    10000
6      TX  Lubbock  Addison       100      250
7      TX   Denton      Jen       200       75
```

You can do:

```
df.groupby(['State','County','Name']).agg(
     Checking = ('Checking','sum'),
     Savings = ('Savings','sum'),
     ).reset_index()
```

#output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help! I don't understand the "Checking" and "Savings" text before both equals signs. What are they doing in the agg function, and why do they not need to be Strings? For example, what is Checking = ('Checking','sum') doing?

Comment: Actually they are the new column names.. you can have any column name. I am keeping it same

Comment: @user603535 please this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53619715/13086128

Comment: Your first suggestion didn't work for me (maybe due to my Python version?), so that's why I was a little confused. Sure enough, I searched around and stumbled upon the very same link you just suggested. Much appreciated!

Comment: if you find the answer useful you can +1✔️ so that other fellow stack members know if he find same doubt as yours.